# when I install ubuntu by deleting my previous os , will my previous programs and programs save data be lost?

Tags: system-installation

I am a user of windows xp , now I am thinking of between switching or dual boot after I have finished the errors in my computer.

I would love dual boot but my harddisk will not be enough so if I delete windows xp will it affect my program and program files?

Comment: Yes, if you install Ubuntu in the same partition where you have installed XP (generally in `C:`) all data in that partition (including Installed programs, My Documents, My Music, Whatever you've saved in Desktop, etc.) will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting Windows XP **WILL** remove the programs and program files from your computer's harddisk.